# I can not parse date/time in Go - Gin

Tags: json, go, parsing, time

I am sending this json:

```json
{"origin":{"lat":23.589367061768648,"lng":58.42860314995051},"destination":null,"vehicle":"WATER_TANKER_600GL","scheduled_time":"2022-07-27T14:16:00Z04:00"}
```

Golang Gin handler function:

```golang
func (config *Config) CreateOrder(c *gin.Context) {

    userID := auth.GetToken(c).ID()

    data := &struct {
        Origin        models.Origin       `json:"origin" binding:"required"`
        Vehicle       VehicleType         `json:"vehicle" binding:"required"`
        Destination   *models.Destination `json:"destination" `
        ScheduledTime *time.Time          `json:"scheduled_time"`
    }{}

    if err := c.ShouldBindWith(data, binding.JSON); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) // -> prints the below error
        res.UnprocessableEntity(c, fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
        return
    }

// rest of the code
}
```

I get this error:

```
parsing time "\"2022-07-27T14:16:00Z04:00\"" as "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"": cannot parse "04:00\"" as "\""
```

Comment: It's either Z or 04:00 not both

Comment: See [docs time example](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-Parse) &  https://go.dev/play/p/o4gqaM0O-0o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [JSON does not define a date or timestamp data type](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp). Transferring a timestamp as a JSON string is possible, but how that timestamp string is interpreted–or should be interpreted–is not written in stone. The standard lib (the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package) supports unmarshaling `time.Time` values from JSON strings, but it does so by requiring them to adhere the RFC 3339 standard, else the unmarshaling will fail.

[`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) implements [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler), and [`Time.UnmarshalJSON()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnmarshalJSON) states that the JSON string must be in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339.html) layout which is:

```
RFC3339 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

The `Z` in the [layout](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Layout) means:

> Numeric time zone offsets format as follows:
>
> ```
> "-0700"  ±hhmm
> "-07:00" ±hh:mm
> "-07"    ±hh
> ```
>
> **Replacing the sign in the format with a Z triggers the ISO 8601 behavior of printing Z instead of an offset for the UTC zone.** Thus:
>
> ```
> "Z0700"  Z or ±hhmm
> "Z07:00" Z or ±hh:mm
> "Z07"    Z or ±hh
> ```

Which means if the time has UTC offset, it should be

```
"2022-07-27T14:16:00Z"
```

If the time has `+04:00` zone, it should be

```
"2022-07-27T14:16:00+04:00"
```

The input `"2022-07-27T14:16:00Z04:00"` is invalid for RFC 3339. Either change your source to provide RFC 3339 compliant timestamp strings, or if you can't or don't want to, you may create your custom type that implements `json.Unmarshaler`, and you handle this non-RFC 3339 format yourself.

Comment: I would add a minor note that, strictly speaking, JSON does not have a data type for time instants, so the fact `encoding/json` is written to interpret strings being unmarshaled to variables of `time.Time` as formatted according to RFC3339 is an implementation detail which will be well hidden in the program. So if I were to code such a program I'd define my own logic to parse these time instants even if in the end it would call out to the standard library's implementation: just to make clear what the expectations are.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for the note, added it to the answer.