# Go json.NewDecoder.Decode convert time.time to 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Tags: json, go, decode, unmarshalling

I am using to json.NewDecoder.Decode to get data from http.response like following

```
    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        var httpResponse models.httpResponse

        err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&httpResponse)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Info(err.Error())
        }
        ....
}


type httpResponse struct {
    SomeField1         string            `json:"somefield1"`
    SomeField2         string            `json:"somefield2"`
    Timestamp1       time.Time           `json:"Timestamp1"`
    Timestamp2       time.Time           `json:"Timestamp2"`
}
```

I noticed that one of the timeStamp Timestamp1 with value("2013-06-25T18:09:22.123321Z") in the response was converted to

> 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

. But another timeStamp Timestamp2 with value("2014-03-26T03:59:59.999Z") has the right value after the Decode.
I've also tried **json.Unmarshal**, same results. Please advise.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: See https://go.dev/play/p/yKVY_ir0Uy4

Comment: Both of those values work for me: [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/9J1Hv-0opay) Please provide an example input JSON, aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that `Time.UnmarshalJSON()` states that the JSON string must be in RFC 3339 layout, check: [I can not parse date/time in Go - Gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136442/i-can-not-parse-date-time-in-go-gin/73136883#73136883)